# '$this->actingAs' is not working with backpack for laravel in phpunit test

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using `backpakcforlaravel` package.
Laravel's provided method '$this->actingAs' is not working with backpack provided middleware.
The middleware is `admin`.
If I check any route inside the above middleware, it returns:

`Expected response status code [200] but received 302. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302.`

The code is as below:

```
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $role = Role::factory()->create([
            'name' => User::ROLE_ADMIN
        ]);
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get(route('admin.homework.detail'));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
```

But, the test works with other routes and middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `backpack` guard you need to specify it in `->actingAs($user, 'backpack')`.

Cheers